# Want to reduce load on CPU by reducing query from all tables to only required ones

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have website in codeigniter version 1, and there is 1 database query which is making CPU load to 100%. I know that this query is of codeigniter framework, as soon as my site gets more than 50 visitors, I have attached image of the query as well please help me if you can.

[image: query image]

Comment: Is `views` a `VIEW` or a `TABLE`? If a `VIEW`, you need to provide the underlying query. If a `TABLE`, have you indexed `article_id`? _(Sidenote: `ORDER BY` doesn't really make a whole lot of sense on that query; though I do not think it would hurt anything.)_

Comment: Codeigniter version 1 is very old. Codeigniter 3.0.4 out now http://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: @Uueerdo  the problem is, site has tons of custom functionalities which we created in CodeIgniter old version so if I want to update, I have fear that those functionalities will stop working, please suggest what should I do.

Comment: @yashbhagchandani I am not familiar with CodeIgniter. Are you not able to change or inspect the underlying MySQL database?